# What to do if MacBook Pro 2017 uses more wattage than the charger can give?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I wanted to ask, what to do if MacBook Pro 2017 uses more wattage than the charger can give? Why I am asking this or thinking this might be a problem? I tried to play some games on BootCamp (playing games on MacBook is another discussion, no hate please) on settings where I got 60FPS without lag but the problem is that my battery is discharging at the time I am playing. I can not recognize the problem on macOS though.

If I bought the mac couple days ago, first they gave me fake charger which f*d up my mac and wouldn't charge at all. Still can not believe that I buy new Mac and get fake charger with it. Then I went back to the store and asked for new Original charger which I then got. I can not see any more problems than the above I described.

Can anybody tell me what to check, what to do, who to contact with? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: where did you get the MacBook?  If you bought a 2017 MacBook Pro a couple of days ago it probably wasn't new. So you'd get whatever charger that was available and would fit your Mac. Sounds like it was a smaller (35 Watt) charger.

Comment: @jmh I bought it from the Apple reseller called mobipunk. They sell demo products and mine is one of them. My charger now is original and is 87W as it should. It is the max W you can get from Apple MacBook charger

Answer (score 1):

You should check the power of your charger and then check the power required for your MacBook Pro. I think you need a 87 Watt charger but smaller chargers will work although they may exhibit the problem you see. You can check the required charger and cables for  your computer [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700).

If your charger is less the 87 Watts your best options are to go back to wherever you bought the computer and explain your problem or buy a new charger from Apple.

Comment: I bought it from the Apple reseller called mobipunk. They sell demo products and mine is one of them. My charger now is original and is 87W as it should. It is the max W you can get from Apple MacBook charger

Comment: 87w is the highest listed in the Apple Store so I would say that is it.  The USB standard says that USB-C can deliver 100w but this might be powering devices, though I would think this goes both directions (charging and powering a device). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#PD for details

Comment: @ThomasNelson So basically if I find some good charger with more Wattage it in theory should deliver more as the USB-C can actually deliver more? Weird is that searching from the web does not give that many of the problem so it is hard to detect what could cause this. There is no way to be sure what apple made. I link one more answer from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/ch4rd8/what_to_do_if_macbook_pro_2017_uses_more_wattage/), gonna try that soon.

Answer (score 0):

MacBooks have been able to demand more power from their battery-pack than is available through the charge supply for a long time, but that's because the Mac-top doesn't actually use charger supply to power the computer unless the battery is missing or faulted out of circuit. They run from the battery-pack 100% of the time, even when connected to charge.

The battery is organised by the little embedded switching processor into two circuits of cells, and each circuit runs the MacBook whilst the other gets a rapid top-up, and at full load - all cores screaming, data flowing, screen burning and WiFi singing, your MacBook Pro can demand - and receive - as much as 130 watts sustained from the battery pack. So it should be no surprise that you can have it on charge and still see battery-life slipping away.

And there's nothing you can do about that behaviour, other than to reduce the machine's workloads. One can get chargers that can put out over 150 watts over USB-PD, but your MacBoook will never negotiate nor accept more than 87W.